# query regarding firebase in my game application

Tags: android, firebase

I am creating a game application which needed google game services.everything is working fine.
Now I want to integrate my application with firebase. But I have query.

1)since I want to use **AdMob**, **Crash Reporting** and **Google Analytics** in the same application so do I have to create 3 different projects in firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to create 3 different projects in order to use `AdMob`, `Crash Reporting` and `Google Analytics`, only one is needed.

Hope it helps.